# Recycleview's onClick and put extra

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Please help!  i have a `recycleview` with search function(base on `JSON` search). i wanna click-able this `recycleview`(mean that getting item's ID where shown in item's view ) and then `PutExtra` this ID to another activity . then another activity get ID. and finally another activity post ID and get values!

this my code , somebody tell my wrongs:):

**AdapterFish.java**

```
public class AdapterFish extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<DataFish> data= Collections.emptyList();
DataFish current;
int currentPos=0;
public String IDHOLDER;
private Context activity;

// create constructor to initialize context and data sent from MainActivity
public AdapterFish(Context context, List<DataFish> data){
    this.context=context;
    inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data=data;
}

// Inflate the layout when ViewHolder created
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_fish, parent,false);
    MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

// Bind data
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    // Get current position of item in RecyclerView to bind data and assign values from list
    MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) holder;
    DataFish current=data.get(position);
    myHolder.company.setText(current.company);
    myHolder.name.setText(current.name);
    myHolder.family.setText(current.family);
    myHolder.id.setText(current.id);
    myHolder.id.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent));

}

// return total item from List
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Context getActivity() {
    return activity;
}

public void setActivity(Context activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}


class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView company;
    TextView name;
    TextView family;
    TextView id;

    // create constructor to get widget reference
    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        company= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.company);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        family = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.family);
        id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    // Click event for all items
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked an item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        final String ItemId = id.getText().toString().trim();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ShowSingleRecordActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("ID", ItemId);
        context.startActivity(intent);



    }

}}
```

**ShowSingleRecordActivity.java (Receiving ID)**

```
public class ShowSingleRecordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

HttpParse httpParse = new HttpParse();
ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Http Url For Filter Student Data from Id Sent from previous activity.
String HttpURL = "http://192.168.137.1/namayeshgah/FilterStudentData.php";

// Http URL for delete Already Open Student Record.
String HttpUrlDeleteRecord = "http://192.168.137.1/namayeshgah/DeleteStudent.php";

String finalResult ;
HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
String ParseResult ;
HashMap<String,String> ResultHash = new HashMap<>();
String FinalJSonObject ;
TextView COMPANY,NAME,FAMILY,GENDER,EMAIL1,EMAIL2,PHONE,FAX,TELLFAX,MOBILE;
String  CompanyHolder ,NameHolder,FamilyHolder,GenderHolder,Email1Holder,Email2Holder,PhoneHolder,FaxHolder,TellfaxHolder,MobileHolder;
Button UpdateButton, DeleteButton;
String TempItem;
ProgressDialog progressDialog2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_single_record);

    COMPANY = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ncompany);
    NAME = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nname);
    FAMILY=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.nfamily);
    GENDER =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ngender);
    EMAIL1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nemail1);
    EMAIL2= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nemail2);
    PHONE= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nphone);
    FAX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nfax);
    TELLFAX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ntellfax);
    MOBILE = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nmobile);


    UpdateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);
    DeleteButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);

    //Receiving the ListView Clicked item value send by previous activity.
    TempItem = getIntent().getStringExtra("ID");

    //Calling method to filter Student Record and open selected record.
    HttpWebCall(TempItem);


    UpdateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(ShowSingleRecordActivity.this,UpdateActivity.class);

            // Sending Student Id, Name, Number and Class to next UpdateActivity.
            intent.putExtra("Id", TempItem);
            intent.putExtra("company",CompanyHolder );
            intent.putExtra("name", NameHolder);
            intent.putExtra("family",FamilyHolder );
            intent.putExtra("gender",GenderHolder );
            intent.putExtra("email1",Email1Holder );
            intent.putExtra("email2",Email2Holder );
            intent.putExtra("phone",PhoneHolder );
            intent.putExtra("fax",FaxHolder );
            intent.putExtra("tellfax",TellfaxHolder );
            intent.putExtra("mobile",MobileHolder );

            startActivity(intent);

            // Finishing current activity after opening next activity.
            finish();

        }
    });

    // Add Click listener on Delete button.
    DeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // Calling Student delete method to delete current record using Student ID.
            StudentDelete(TempItem);

        }
    });

}

// Method to Delete Student Record
public void StudentDelete(final String StudentID) {

    class StudentDeleteClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog2 = ProgressDialog.show(ShowSingleRecordActivity.this, "Loading Data", null, true, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {

            super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);

            progressDialog2.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(ShowSingleRecordActivity.this, httpResponseMsg.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            finish();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // Sending STUDENT id.
            hashMap.put("StudentID", params[0]);

            finalResult = httpParse.postRequest(hashMap, HttpUrlDeleteRecord);

            return finalResult;
        }
    }

    StudentDeleteClass studentDeleteClass = new StudentDeleteClass();

    studentDeleteClass.execute(StudentID);
}


//Method to show current record Current Selected Record
public void HttpWebCall(final String PreviousListViewClickedItem){

    class HttpWebCallFunction extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ShowSingleRecordActivity.this,"Loading Data",null,true,true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {

            super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);

            pDialog.dismiss();

            //Storing Complete JSon Object into String Variable.
            FinalJSonObject = httpResponseMsg ;

            //Parsing the Stored JSOn String to GetHttpResponse Method.
            new GetHttpResponse(ShowSingleRecordActivity.this).execute();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            ResultHash.put("StudentID",params[0]);

            ParseResult = httpParse.postRequest(ResultHash, HttpURL);

            return ParseResult;
        }
    }

    HttpWebCallFunction httpWebCallFunction = new HttpWebCallFunction();

    httpWebCallFunction.execute(PreviousListViewClickedItem);
}


// Parsing Complete JSON Object.
private class GetHttpResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    public Context context;

    public GetHttpResponse(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
    {
        try
        {
            if(FinalJSonObject != null)
            {
                JSONArray jsonArray = null;

                try {
                    jsonArray = new JSONArray(FinalJSonObject);

                    JSONObject jsonObject;

                    for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing Student Name, Phone Number, Class into Variables.
                        CompanyHolder = jsonObject.getString("company");
                        NameHolder = jsonObject.getString("name");
                        FamilyHolder= jsonObject.getString("family");
                        GenderHolder= jsonObject.getString("gender");
                        Email1Holder = jsonObject.getString("email1");
                        Email2Holder = jsonObject.getString("email2");
                        PhoneHolder = jsonObject.getString("phone");
                        FaxHolder = jsonObject.getString("fax");
                        TellfaxHolder = jsonObject.getString("tellfax");
                        MobileHolder = jsonObject.getString("mobile");







                    }
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {

        // Setting Student Name, Phone Number, Class into TextView after done all process .
        COMPANY.setText(CompanyHolder);
        NAME.setText(NameHolder);
        FAMILY.setText(FamilyHolder);
        GENDER.setText(GenderHolder);
        EMAIL1.setText(Email1Holder);
        EMAIL2.setText(Email2Holder);
        PHONE.setText(PhoneHolder);
        FAX.setText(FaxHolder);
        TELLFAX.setText(TellfaxHolder);
        MOBILE.setText(MobileHolder);





    }
}
```

and Searching.java

```
public class searching extends AppCompatActivity {

// CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
private RecyclerView mRVFish;
private AdapterFish mAdapter;

SearchView searchView = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.searching);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // adds item to action bar
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_main, menu);

    // Get Search item from action bar and Get Search service
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) searching.this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    if (searchItem != null) {
        searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    }
    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(searching.this.getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconified(false);
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// Every time when you press search button on keypad an Activity is recreated which in turn calls this function
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Get search query and create object of class AsyncFetch
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        if (searchView != null) {
            searchView.clearFocus();
        }
        new AsyncFetch(query).execute();

    }
}

// Create class AsyncFetch
private class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(searching.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;
    String searchQuery;

    public AsyncFetch(String searchQuery){
        this.searchQuery=searchQuery;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            // Enter URL address where your php file resides
            url = new URL("http://192.168.137.1/namayeshgah/search/fish-search.php");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
        try {

            // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            // setDoInput and setDoOutput to true as we send and recieve data
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // add parameter to our above url
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("searchQuery", searchQuery);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return e1.toString();
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            // Check if successful connection made
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                return (result.toString());

            } else {
                return("Connection error");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.dismiss();
        List<DataFish> data=new ArrayList<>();

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        if(result.equals("no rows")) {
            Toast.makeText(searching.this, "No Results found for entered query", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{

            try {

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    DataFish fishData = new DataFish();
                    fishData.company = json_data.getString("company");
                    fishData.name = json_data.getString("name");
                    fishData.family = json_data.getString("family");
                    fishData.id = json_data.getString("id");

                    data.add(fishData);
                }

                // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview
                mRVFish = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.fishPriceList);
                mAdapter = new AdapterFish(searching.this, data);
                mRVFish.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mRVFish.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(searching.this));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // You to understand what actually error is and handle it appropriately
                Toast.makeText(searching.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(searching.this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: share your whole **AdapterFish.java** class

Comment: what you want to pass to another actvity

Comment: id that showed in recycleview item view

Comment: try to read about parcalable.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DataFish newCurrent=data.get(getAdapterPosition());
        Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked an item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        final String ItemId = newCurrent.id;
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ShowSingleRecordActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("ID", ItemId);
        context.startActivity(intent);



    }
```

Comment: but still not working :( ... i think putextras that you send is working but ShowSingleRecordActivity.java dosent show values in layout ... can you check this class?

Comment: @ALI sure i will check it

Comment: @ALI what you retrieving in your **ShowSingleRecordActivity**

Comment: it seems ID send to my php and 10 parameter retrieving from server (like company , name ,....) then put extras this parameters to another activity to edit my table in server

Comment: @ALI did it wok or not

Comment: want to send my php?

Comment: @ALI i means did you receive correct id in **ShowSingleRecordActivity**

Comment: how To understand this? sryy im newobe :(

Comment: @ALI add this  **Log.e("ID",""+TempItem);** before **TempItem = getIntent().getStringExtra("ID");** this and check your logcat value

Comment: tanks bro :) really worked ... i just use your method and another !

Comment: @ALI happy to help you enjoy codding

Comment: i'am a newobe in stack over flow ... what did you said?

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code hope so it will be working.

```
public class AdapterFish extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<DataFish> data= Collections.emptyList();
    DataFish current;
    int currentPos=0;
    public String IDHOLDER;
    private Context activity;

    // create constructor to initialize context and data sent from MainActivity
    public AdapterFish(Context context, List<DataFish> data){
        this.context=context;
        inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=data;
    }

    // Inflate the layout when ViewHolder created
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_fish, parent,false);
        MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    // Bind data
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        // Get current position of item in RecyclerView to bind data and assign values from list
        MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) holder;
        DataFish current=data.get(position);
        myHolder.company.setText(current.company);
        myHolder.name.setText(current.name);
        myHolder.family.setText(current.family);
        myHolder.id.setText(current.id);
        myHolder.id.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent));


        ((MyHolder ) holder).itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked an item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //final String ItemId = id.getText().toString().trim();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ShowSingleRecordActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("ID", current.id);
            context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

    }

    // return total item from List
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Context getActivity() {
        return activity;
    }

    public void setActivity(Context activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }


    class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        TextView company;
        TextView name;
        TextView family;
        TextView id;

        // create constructor to get widget reference
        public MyHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            company= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.company);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            family = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.family);
            id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        // Click event for all items
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

              }

    }}
```

ShowSingleRecordActivity.java (Receiving ID)

```
public class ShowSingleRecordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

HttpParse httpParse = new HttpParse();
ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Http Url For Filter Student Data from Id Sent from previous activity.
String HttpURL = "http://192.168.137.1/namayeshgah/FilterStudentData.php";

// Http URL for delete Already Open Student Record.
String HttpUrlDeleteRecord = "http://192.168.137.1/namayeshgah/DeleteStudent.php";

String finalResult ;
HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
String ParseResult ;
HashMap<String,String> ResultHash = new HashMap<>();
String FinalJSonObject ;
TextView COMPANY,NAME,FAMILY,GENDER,EMAIL1,EMAIL2,PHONE,FAX,TELLFAX,MOBILE;
String  CompanyHolder ,NameHolder,FamilyHolder,GenderHolder,Email1Holder,Email2Holder,PhoneHolder,FaxHolder,TellfaxHolder,MobileHolder;
Button UpdateButton, DeleteButton;
String TempItem;
ProgressDialog progressDialog2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_single_record);

    COMPANY = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ncompany);
    NAME = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nname);
    FAMILY=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.nfamily);
    GENDER =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ngender);
    EMAIL1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nemail1);
    EMAIL2= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nemail2);
    PHONE= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nphone);
    FAX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nfax);
    TELLFAX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ntellfax);
    MOBILE = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nmobile);


    UpdateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);
    DeleteButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);

    //Receiving the ListView Clicked item value send by previous activity.
    TempItem = getIntent().getExtra("ID");
    System.out.println("TempItem=============>"+TempItem )

    //Calling method to filter Student Record and open selected record.
    if(null != TempItem){
     HttpWebCall(TempItem);
    }else{
      Toast.makeText(context, "Item ID is not get from list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }



    UpdateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(ShowSingleRecordActivity.this,UpdateActivity.class);

            // Sending Student Id, Name, Number and Class to next UpdateActivity.
            intent.putExtra("Id", TempItem);
            intent.putExtra("company",CompanyHolder );
            intent.putExtra("name", NameHolder);
            intent.putExtra("family",FamilyHolder );
            intent.putExtra("gender",GenderHolder );
            intent.putExtra("email1",Email1Holder );
            intent.putExtra("email2",Email2Holder );
            intent.putExtra("phone",PhoneHolder );
            intent.putExtra("fax",FaxHolder );
            intent.putExtra("tellfax",TellfaxHolder );
            intent.putExtra("mobile",MobileHolder );

            startActivity(intent);

            // Finishing current activity after opening next activity.
            finish();

        }
    });

    // Add Click listener on Delete button.
    DeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // Calling Student delete method to delete current record using Student ID.
            StudentDelete(TempItem);

        }
    });

}

// Method to Delete Student Record
public void StudentDelete(final String StudentID) {

    class StudentDeleteClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog2 = ProgressDialog.show(ShowSingleRecordActivity.this, "Loading Data", null, true, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {

            super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);

            progressDialog2.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(ShowSingleRecordActivity.this, httpResponseMsg.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            finish();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // Sending STUDENT id.
            hashMap.put("StudentID", params[0]);

            finalResult = httpParse.postRequest(hashMap, HttpUrlDeleteRecord);

            return finalResult;
        }
    }

    StudentDeleteClass studentDeleteClass = new StudentDeleteClass();

    studentDeleteClass.execute(StudentID);
}


//Method to show current record Current Selected Record
public void HttpWebCall(final String PreviousListViewClickedItem){

    class HttpWebCallFunction extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ShowSingleRecordActivity.this,"Loading Data",null,true,true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {

            super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);

            pDialog.dismiss();

            //Storing Complete JSon Object into String Variable.
            FinalJSonObject = httpResponseMsg ;

            //Parsing the Stored JSOn String to GetHttpResponse Method.
            new GetHttpResponse(ShowSingleRecordActivity.this).execute();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            ResultHash.put("StudentID",params[0]);

            ParseResult = httpParse.postRequest(ResultHash, HttpURL);

            return ParseResult;
        }
    }

    HttpWebCallFunction httpWebCallFunction = new HttpWebCallFunction();

    httpWebCallFunction.execute(PreviousListViewClickedItem);
}


// Parsing Complete JSON Object.
private class GetHttpResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    public Context context;

    public GetHttpResponse(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
    {
        try
        {
            if(FinalJSonObject != null)
            {
                JSONArray jsonArray = null;

                try {
                    jsonArray = new JSONArray(FinalJSonObject);

                    JSONObject jsonObject;

                    for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing Student Name, Phone Number, Class into Variables.
                        CompanyHolder = jsonObject.getString("company");
                        NameHolder = jsonObject.getString("name");
                        FamilyHolder= jsonObject.getString("family");
                        GenderHolder= jsonObject.getString("gender");
                        Email1Holder = jsonObject.getString("email1");
                        Email2Holder = jsonObject.getString("email2");
                        PhoneHolder = jsonObject.getString("phone");
                        FaxHolder = jsonObject.getString("fax");
                        TellfaxHolder = jsonObject.getString("tellfax");
                        MobileHolder = jsonObject.getString("mobile");







                    }
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {

        // Setting Student Name, Phone Number, Class into TextView after done all process .
        COMPANY.setText(CompanyHolder);
        NAME.setText(NameHolder);
        FAMILY.setText(FamilyHolder);
        GENDER.setText(GenderHolder);
        EMAIL1.setText(Email1Holder);
        EMAIL2.setText(Email2Holder);
        PHONE.setText(PhoneHolder);
        FAX.setText(FaxHolder);
        TELLFAX.setText(TellfaxHolder);
        MOBILE.setText(MobileHolder);





    }
}
```

Comment: hey just try to print first in ShowSingleRecordActivity in onCreate() after gentIntent..eg  System.out.println("ID is=============>"+TempItem);

Answer (score 0):

hopefully this will work .. but what exactly is your problem ? is it detecting the clicked value or passing ID to new Activity?

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    // Get current position of item in RecyclerView to bind data and assign values from list
    MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) holder;
    DataFish current=data.get(position);
    myHolder.setTag(current);   //<--added
    myHolder.company.setText(current.company);
    myHolder.name.setText(current.name);
    myHolder.family.setText(current.family);
    myHolder.id.setText(current.id);
    myHolder.id.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent));

    ((MyHolder ) holder).itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked an item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                DataFish clickedData = (DataFish) v.getTag();   //<-- pull data from tag
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ShowSingleRecordActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("ID", clickedData.id);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: both ... i dont know where is problem ?!

Comment: did you see the "You clicked an item" toast when clicked an item?

Comment: from @Anonymous answer , try change to this ->

    TempItem = getIntent().getExtras().getString("ID");

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line in **ShowSingleRecordActivity**

```
TempItem = getIntent().getStringExtra("ID");
```

to

```
TempItem = getIntent().getExtras().getString("ID");
```

Comment: sorry that was a slight mistake in hurry..check the updated code.This will solve your problem